# Unable to add Compass to a Rails 3.1 app using the Less Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, compass-sass

I have been unable to add Compass using the Less Framework to my Rails 3.1 app. Both the compass and compass-less-plugin gems are installed and are included in the gemfile as well as the gemfile.lock file under "Dependencies". I run the following command in Terminal, and it doesn't recognize Less Framework.

```
j(film_repo)$ compass init rails . --using less
No such framework: "less"
```

My environment includes rails 3.1.0.rc4 and ruby 1.9.2-head as well as the following gems (among others):

```
compass 0.11.4 
compass-less-plugin 1.0 
haml 3.1.2 
sass 3.1.4, 3.1.2 
sass-rails 3.1.0.rc4...
```

I created an issue on Github for the compass-less-plugin https://github.com/willhw/compass-less-plugin/issues/4 , but it may not be the source of the issue.

Thanks in advance for any guidance and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue as you, but with Rails 3.0.9 project. What worked for me, is the following:

```
$ compass init rails -r less . --using less
```

(notice the -r which requires the less plugin)